# Child theme not picking up parent textColor

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

Here is what I got:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
.
.

</style>

<style name="MyTheme.child">
.
.
.

</style>
```

The theme `MyTheme.child` only changes text colour if I put the `android:textColor` item inside it instead of inheriting it from parent.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

that happens because when you try to get the wanted textColor, you are using : MyTheme (the default one) and not the one created by you. 
If you want to use your's you have to give details for the wanted color there, and declare the style at your new one.

Comment: `MyTheme` is my own custom theme, how is it the default one?

Comment: also, in the layout im using `MyTheme.child` and not `MyTheme`